# How to run a program with opencv3.0 that was done using C++ and OpenCV 2.4?

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I am trying to run a program that was developed using VS C++ with Opencv 2.4 but i am using Opencv 3.0.

I tried to change `cv.h` to `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` but it did not work. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Which version of 2.4? Without seeing the code is really hard to tell

Comment: You need to refactor your code to cope with the OpenCV 3.0. Check the [transition guide](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0)